# Why do texture samplers seem to bleed into other instances when rendering multiple instances of the same mesh with differing textures

Tags: texture, vulkan

I originally asked this question on the gamdev stack exchange but was told by a friend I would be better served here.

[Original Question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205276/why-do-texture-samplers-seem-to-bleed-into-other-instances-when-rendering-multip)

So I will start off by laying out the relevant structure of my program.

I am using vulkan to render the same mesh over a few instances. To do this I have:

- a vertex buffer, used per vertex, which is an array of the following structure

```rust
pub struct ShaderVertexData {
    pub position: na::Vector3<f32>,
    pub uv: na::Vector2<f32>,
    pub normal: na::Vector3<f32>,
}
```

- an "instance" buffer, used per instance, which is an array of this structure.

```rust
pub struct InstanceData {
    pub model: [[f32; 4]; 4],
    pub texture_index: u32,
}
```

- An array of textures provided via a descriptor set

```rust
let descriptor_binding_flags = [vk::DescriptorBindingFlags::VARIABLE_DESCRIPTOR_COUNT];
let mut descriptorset_layout_binding_flags =
    vk::DescriptorSetLayoutBindingFlagsCreateInfo::builder()
        .binding_flags(&descriptor_binding_flags);

let layout_bindings = [DescriptorSetLayoutBinding::builder()
    .stage_flags(vk::ShaderStageFlags::FRAGMENT)
    .binding(0)
    .descriptor_count(MAX_IMAGES)
    .descriptor_type(vk::DescriptorType::COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER)
    .build()];

let descriptor_set_layout_info = vk::DescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo::builder()
    .bindings(&layout_bindings)
    .push_next(&mut descriptorset_layout_binding_flags);

let descriptor_set_layout_texture = unsafe {
    logical_device.create_descriptor_set_layout(&descriptor_set_layout_info, None)
}?;

let descriptor_pool_sizes = [vk::DescriptorPoolSize::builder()
    .ty(vk::DescriptorType::COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER)
    .descriptor_count(MAX_IMAGES * 3)
    .build()];

let descriptor_pool_info = vk::DescriptorPoolCreateInfo::builder()
    .pool_sizes(&descriptor_pool_sizes)
    .max_sets(3);

let descriptor_pool =
    unsafe { logical_device.create_descriptor_pool(&descriptor_pool_info, None) }?;

let desc_layouts_texture = vec![descriptor_set_layout_texture; 3];
// TODO: Move this into the texture code to allocate as needed. For now I just hard-code 2 textures.
let mut variable = DescriptorSetVariableDescriptorCountAllocateInfo::builder()
    .descriptor_counts(&[2, 2, 2]);
let descriptor_set_allocate_info = vk::DescriptorSetAllocateInfo::builder()
    .descriptor_pool(descriptor_pool)
    .set_layouts(&desc_layouts_texture)
    .push_next(&mut variable);

let descriptor_sets =
    unsafe { logical_device.allocate_descriptor_sets(&descriptor_set_allocate_info) }?;

let descriptor_set_layouts = [descriptor_set_layout_texture];

let pipelinelayout_info = vk::PipelineLayoutCreateInfo::builder()
    .push_constant_ranges(&push_constant_ranges)
    .set_layouts(&descriptor_set_layouts);

//------------------------------------------------
// Later I copy in the texture info
//------------------------------------------------
let descriptor_image_infos = self.texture_store.get_descriptor_image_info();
let descriptor_writes = [vk::WriteDescriptorSet {
    descriptor_type: vk::DescriptorType::COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER,
    dst_set: self.graphics_pipeline.descriptor_sets
        [frame_buffer_info.image_index as usize],
    dst_binding: 0,
    dst_array_element: 0,
    p_image_info: descriptor_image_infos.as_ptr(),
    descriptor_count: 2,
    ..Default::default()
}];
```

I then have the following shaders

```
// vertex
#version 450

layout(push_constant)uniform constants{
    mat4 proj;
}PushConstants;

layout(location=0)in mat4 model;
layout(location=4)in uint tex_id;
layout(location=5)in vec3 position;
layout(location=6)in vec2 uv;
layout(location=7)in vec3 normal;

layout(location=0)out vec2 uv_for_fragment_shader;
layout(location=1)out uint tex_id_for_fragment_shader;

void main(){
    gl_Position=PushConstants.proj*model*vec4(position,1);
    tex_id_for_fragment_shader = tex_id;
    uv_for_fragment_shader=uv;
}

// fragment
#version 450
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : require

layout(set=0,binding=0)uniform sampler2D tex_samplers[];

layout(location=0)in vec2 uv_from_vertex_shader;
layout(location=1)in flat uint tex_id_from_vertex_shader;

layout(location=0)out vec4 output_colour;

void main(){
    output_colour = texture(tex_samplers[tex_id_from_vertex_shader], uv_from_vertex_shader);
}
```

Finally I draw the instances like so

```rust
self.logical_device.cmd_push_constants(
    commandbuffer,
    self.graphics_pipeline.layout,
    vk::ShaderStageFlags::VERTEX,
    0,
    &std::mem::transmute::<[[f32; 4]; 4], [u8; 64]>(projection),
);

self.logical_device.cmd_bind_descriptor_sets(
    commandbuffer,
    vk::PipelineBindPoint::GRAPHICS,
    self.graphics_pipeline.layout,
    0,
    &[self.graphics_pipeline.descriptor_sets
        [frame_buffer_info.image_index as usize]],
    &[],
);
self.cube.bind(&self.logical_device, commandbuffer);

self.logical_device.cmd_bind_vertex_buffers(
    commandbuffer,
    VertexBufferBindings::InstanceBuffer as u32,
    &[self.instance_buffer.buffer],
    &[0],
);

self.logical_device.cmd_draw_indexed(
    commandbuffer,
    self.cube.index_count() as u32,
    4,
    0,
    0,
    0,
);
```

With that out of the way we can get to the problem at hand, The texture samplers seem to bleed over into the separate instances

[image: 2 Cubes with different textures but patches of each-others textures]

I have checked that the texture index itself is consistent across the entire instance by rendering

```
output_colour = vec4(tex_id_from_vertex_shader, 0,0,1);
```

And I get no artefacts

[image: No artefacts]

So it seems like the sampler itself is hanging around where it shouldn't. Any idea what might be causing this to happen?

If it matters I am on an AMD Radeon 7900 XTX and using the latest drivers

Comment: I don't know enough about Vulkan to identify the actual problem, but the fact that the errors are in small patches, with rectangular edges, that don't match your geometry is a sign that something is going wrong with the execution of the fragment shader (which is done in small patches like that).

Comment: It seems as though you are correct, its as though the sampler is just locked for the entire fragment. Interestingly enough. Adding a branch in the code like this:

```

if (tex_id_from_vertex_shader == 0) {

        albedo = texture(tex_samplers[0], uv_from_vertex_shader);

    } else {

        albedo = texture(tex_samplers[1], uv_from_vertex_shader);

    }

```

Works just fine. So it is some kind of optimisation?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got an answer on the [AMD Forums](https://community.amd.com/t5/opengl-vulkan/vulkan-fragment-shader-bug-when-using-array-of-textures/m-p/600999/thread-id/4659#M4661).

The issue was that you need to tell the GPU when you plan on indexing resource arrays with non uniform values.

My shader now looks like this:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : require

layout(set=0,binding=0)uniform sampler2D tex_samplers[];

layout(location=0)in vec2 uv_from_vertex_shader;
layout(location=1)in vec3 normal_from_vertex_shader;
layout(location=2)in flat uint tex_id_from_vertex_shader;


layout(location=0)out vec4 output_colour;

void main(){
    vec4 albedo = texture(tex_samplers[nonuniformEXT(tex_id_from_vertex_shader)], uv_from_vertex_shader);
    float light = clamp(dot(normal_from_vertex_shader, normalize(vec3(1,1,1))), 0.2, 1);
    output_colour =  vec4(albedo.rgb * light, albedo.a);
}
```

The important part is the `nonuniformEXT` that wraps the index

It is also worth mentioning that technically this also requires that you enable `shaderSampledImageArrayNonUniformIndexing` on your `VkPhysicalDeviceDescriptorIndexingFeatures`

Comment: Do you have the validation layers turned on? This error should have been reported by the layers.

Comment: Yeah I do have them enabled. Perhaps there is some specific config needed to catch this flavour of error but this didn't show up for me

Comment: In the Vulkan Configurator under "Validation" in  VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation->Validation Areas->Shader-Based->GPU-Assisted->Check descriptor indexing accesses Should trigger the error.